# When I use Hadoop, I get this error in Hive

Tags: mysql, hive, ambari

can somebody help? thanks in advance

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: The hortonworks sanboxes are deprecated. Try the cloudera ones

Answer (score 3):

@Miguel   The error is suggesting an issue starting mysql.  Please login to sandbox and execute the command to see what's going on.   Additionally, you may need to manually install mysql mysql-server or mariadb mariadb-server depending on your version.   This is a requirement.   You will need to be sure that Hive is configured correctly for mysql, and uses a user and table that has been created for hive:

```
CREATE DATABASE hive;
CREATE USER 'hive'@'sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'hive';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'hive'@'sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Also you need to make sure that Ambari-hive can see mysql:

> To use MySQL with Hive, you must download the https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ from MySQL. Once downloaded to the Ambari Server host, run: 
>   ambari-server setup --jdbc-db=mysql --jdbc-driver=/path/to/mysql/com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

The commands for this in centos are:

```
yum install mysql-connector-java && ambari-server setup --jdbc-db=mysql --jdbc-driver=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
```

Comment: hi... thanks for the help... I just found out mysql is not running... when I try to run it using Putty I get "can't connect to local mySQL server throuhg socket /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'... I tried to run it but it needed a password as root... which I had no idea... any sugestion?

Comment: @MiguelAngelGonzalez Whoever installed the cluster and gave the MySQL credentials to Ambari, it shouldve asked for user and password.... We cant tell you how to get your root or database passwords

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine in Ubuntu... I could not make it work in windows. But at least working now. Thanks.